# Installing wpscan and metasploit

Tags: software-installation, metasploit

I installed metasploit and all dependencies following the instructions [here](http://www.darkoperator.com/installing-metasploit-in-ubunt/):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libreadline-dev libssl-dev libpq5 libpq-dev libreadline5 libsqlite3-dev libpcap-dev openjdk-7-jre git-core autoconf postgresql pgadmin3 curl zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev vncviewer libyaml-dev curl zlib1g-dev
```

and using RVM

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
rvm install 2.1.9
rvm use 2.1.9 --default
ruby -v
```

While metasploit is working well, when I installed wpscan with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev ruby-dev build-essential libgmp-dev
git clone https://github.com/wpscanteam/wpscan.git
cd wpscan
sudo gem install bundler && bundle install --without test
```

and try to run it, I get an error:

```
 cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
```

But I've installed the bundler and all dependencies for it and for metasploit. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain what you did to install and what your error is. [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/286848/edit) your post and add information to thequestion.

Comment: I don't know anything about wpscan, but your command `sudo gem install bundler && bundle install` ran the first part with sudo but the `bundle install...` as (whatever user you were at the prompt). Perhaps you need `sudo bundle install....` ?